# Loading moment.js as a dependency with webpack?

Tags: webpack, momentjs

After installing moment.js with npm:

`npm install --save moment`

...what do I have to put into `webpack.config.dev.js` so that I don't get:

> error 'moment' is not defined

Comment: Are you importing `moment` in the file you want to use it in?

Comment: As @JimStewart says, it would be helpful if you could show us how you're importing the code (and the complete minimal example if possible!)